# Chicken breast in slow cooker

Tags: chicken, potatoes, slow-cooking, onions, herbs

I’m new to slow cooking and wanting to slow cook some chicken breast. I put in potato’s, onion and herbs along with whole chicken breast. Will this just burn onto the crock pot with no liquid in or will steam keep the moisture in the meat?

Comment: In my experience, not enough liquid when using a crock pot is a very rare occurrence.  Too much liquid (water) is usually the problem, resulting in a serious lack of flavor.

Answer (score 2):

There is moisture in the onions and chicken.  Yes it should cook fine.

I have put a roast in the slow cooker dry and it worked.